# Nlog debugger target messages do not show in DebugView (but Debug.WriteLine do )

Tags: .net, debugging, nlog, debugview

My program is a c# windows form app. I am running the exe outside of VS. 
Nlog debugger target messages do not show in DebugView, but direct  Debug.WriteLine messages do. 
Both show up on VS output console when running app from inside VS.
Any idea? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Debugger-Target](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Debugger-target) writes to [System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Log - Posts a message for the attached debugger.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.log.aspx)

The [OutputDebugString-Target](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/OutputDebugString-target) writes to [OutputDebugString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/da-dk/library/windows/desktop/aa363362.aspx) that can be monitored by [DebugView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/debugview) (And friends)

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I should have known that NLog had a special target for even an obscure purpose like this one  :)